# $\lim_{x \to 0}(\frac{1}{\log (x+ \sqrt{1+x^2})}-\frac{1}{\log (1-x)})$ - point me to error

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate
>   $$\lim_{x \to 0}\left[\frac{1}{\log (x+ \sqrt{1+x^2})}-\frac{1}{\log (1-x)}\right]$$

Here is my attempt. I know I made some mistake here. I am getting $-\infty$. Please point me to error. Textbook exercise solution is given as $-\dfrac12$.
The given limit is 
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac {\ln (1-x)-\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})}{\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})\ln(1-x)}$$
Applying L'Hôpital's rule
$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\dfrac{-1}{1-x}-\dfrac{1}{x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\left(1+ \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\left(1+\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\ln(1-x)-\dfrac{\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})}{1-x}}$$ is $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\dfrac{-1}{1-x}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\ln({1-x})-\dfrac{\ln (x+\sqrt{1+x^2})}{1-x}} = -\infty.$$

Comment: Please, edit your question and write it using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).

Comment: This really isn't legible.

Comment: the Limit is interminate

Comment: edited @Pippo 
Pls check

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner edited pls check

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown edited pls check

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=acc0a7e1a01e35f904fbdc148987612d&title=Limits%20Calculator&theme=blue&i0=3x%5E3%2Bx%2B2&i1=x&i2=-infinite&podSelect=&includepodid=Limit&podstate=Limit__Show%20steps&showAssumptions=1&showWarnings=1

Comment: @anirudhb There is no need of Hopital here, this difference is not an indeterminate form! On the other hand, if you change the sign and take the sum, the result is $1/2$.

Comment: Your question has a typo. If you have $\log(1+x)$ instead of $\log(1-x)$ then the answer is indeed $-1/2$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552661/proving-lim-limits-x-to0-left-frac1-logx-sqrt1x2-frac1-log1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of L'Hopital rule here, this difference is not an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form)!
$$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{\log (x+ \sqrt{1+x^2})}=+\infty\quad\text{and}\quad
\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{\log (1-x)}=-\infty.$$
Hence
$$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\left(\frac{1}{\log (x+ \sqrt{1+x^2})}-\frac{1}{\log (1-x)}\right)=+\infty-(-\infty)=+\infty.$$
In a similar way, we have that the limit is $-\infty$ as $x\to 0^-$ (and therefore the limit at $0$ does not exist).

On the other hand, by taking the sum, you may apply Hopital two times (a bit hard) or you may use Taylor expansions: as $x\to 0$, 
$$\begin{align*}\frac{1}{\log (x+ \sqrt{1+x^2})}+\frac{1}{\log (1-x)}&=
\frac{\log (1-x)+\log (1+x+ \frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2))}{x\cdot (-x)+o(x^2)}\\
&=\frac{(-x-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2))+(x+ \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2))}{x\cdot (-x)+o(x^2)}\to \frac{1}{2}.\end{align*}$$

Comment: It is ($\infty-\infty$) right? this is indeterminate form.

Comment: how is it $+- \infty$ for 1st one and $-+ \infty $ for 2nd one. Whn we put x = 0 we get 1/ log1 = $\infty$. Pls enlighten

Comment: @anirudhb NO, it is $+\infty-(-\infty)=+\infty+\infty$ when $x\to 0^+$, and $-\infty-(+\infty)=-\infty-\infty$ when $x\to 0^-$.

Comment: @anirudhb "1/ log1 = ∞" is not enough. You need the sign of this infinity!!

Comment: can u pls elaborate on this? i do not know about this. Atleast point me to some part in textbook. If $x \to 0^+, say x = 0.01, \ln (1-x) = \ln (1-0.01) = \ln 0.99 ~ \ln 1 = 0$ Pls clarify

Comment: Note that $\ln(1-x)<0$ for $x\in (0,1)$. Hence, in $x\to 0^+$, $\ln(1-x)$ goes to $0^-$ and $1/0^-=-\infty$. Similar argument for $x<0$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @anirudhb Any further doubt?

Comment: No Sir, crystall clear. I am really amazwd at the way the people in this forum solve problems. Text books do not provide such clarity. May be it takes time to digest in this way

Answer (score 1):

after applying the rules of L'Hopital we get
$${\frac {\sqrt {{x}^{2}+1}+1-x}{\ln  \left( x+\sqrt {{x}^{2}+1}
 \right) \sqrt {{x}^{2}+1}+\ln  \left( 1-x \right) x-\ln  \left( 1-x
 \right) }}
$$ and for $x$ tends to Zero we get that the Limit is undefined

Comment: got it! thnk you. it is $\infty$

Answer (score 1):

Let's have $x=\sinh(u)$ with $u\to 0$.

Since $\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})=u\quad$  we get

$f(x)=\dfrac 1u-\dfrac 1{\ln(1-\sinh u)}=\dfrac 1u+\dfrac 1{-\sinh u +o(\sinh u)}=\dfrac 1u-\dfrac 1{-u+o(u)}=\dfrac 2u+o(\frac 1u)$

And this has no limit in zero, since the left and right limits are infinite with different sign and disagree.

Comment: this is too good, brilliant! :)